# A miscomprehension of how to compute $E[X^2]$.

Tags: probability, expectation

During a question concerning the Birthday Paradox, given P is the number of pairs of people with the same birthday in a group of 20 people and assuming there are 365 possible birth-days, I am to compute the variance. My problem is computing $E[P^2]$. What my teacher did is:  The number of pairs of pairs
that have no common person is ${20\choose 2}\cdot {18\choose 2}$, the number of pairs of pairs that have precisely one person in common ${20\choose 2}\cdot 2\cdot 18$, hence $E[P^2]={20\choose 2}\cdot {18\choose 2}\cdot ({1\over 365})^2+{20\choose 2}\cdot 2\cdot 18\cdot ({1\over 365})^2+{20\choose 2}\cdot ({1\over 365})$.

What is the explanation for looking at pairs of pairs? What is the explanation of looking at pairs with no common persons? How does it follow the formula, if there is any, for computing $E[X^2]$? I will really appreciate any explanation of this or any explanation as for how to compute $E[X^2]$ for P or in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $n:=\binom{20}{2}$ pairs in total. Give each pair a number and let $P_i$ take value $1$ if the two persons of pair $i$ have the same birthday and let $P_i=0$ otherwise. This for $i=1,\dots,n$. The number of pairs having the same birthday equals: $$P=\sum_{i=1}^nP_i$$
and consequently $$P^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nP_iP_j$$
hence$$\mathbb EP^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb EP_iP_j$$

By evaluating $\mathbb EP_iP_j=\mathbb P(P_i=P_j=1)$ three cases must be discerned:

- $i=j$ and (automatically) there are $2$ persons involved.
- $i\neq j$ and there are $3$ persons involved.
- $i\neq j$ and there are $4$ persons involved.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I understand it way better now. And still: I am no sure I have fully understood: what do you exactly mean by saying $i$ people involved? In what way?

Comment: Let $1,2,3,4$ denote persons. If $P=\{1,2\}$ (a pair of two persons) and $Q=\{3,4\}$ then all $4$ persons are involved if it comes to $PQ$. However if e.g. $R=\{2,4\}$ then $3$ persons ($1,2,4$) are involved if it comes to $PR$. If $S=P$ then $2$ persons are involved if it comes to $PS$. In these cases you come to different outcomes if $\mathbb EP_iP_j$ is calculated.

Comment: So what you mean is: either Pi and Pj are the same pair, or these are different pair but one person is in two of them(The birthday is of course the same), or these are two different couples, whose intersection is empty. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying.

Comment: That is a fantastic explanation. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. You are very welcome.